# error: Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPathNotFoundException: 'No such file' in c#

Tags: c#, client, sftp

so I have this code:

```
public static void UploadSFTPFile(string host, string username,
    string password, string sourcefile, string destinationpath, int port)
    {
        string Ip = "";
        String strHostName = string.Empty;
        IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(strHostName);
        IPAddress[] addr = ipEntry.AddressList;

        for (int i = 0; i < addr.Length; i++)
        {
            Ip = (addr[i].ToString());
        }
        using (SftpClient client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
        {
            client.Connect();
            client.ChangeDirectory(destinationpath);
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourcefile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
                client.UploadFile(fs, Path.GetFileName(sourcefile));

            }
            client.WriteAllText("C:/Users/Public/Documents/192.168.0.112.json", "jeff");
        }
    }
```

I use this method to upload  files in my sftp server.
this works perfectly, but I also try to write something in the file:

```
 client.WriteAllText("C:/Users/Public/Documents/Test.json", "jeff");
```

this is where I het the error message:

```
Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPathNotFoundException: 'No such file'
```

what am I doing wrong this is where the file is located and I am admin.

Comment: sftp is secure file transfer protocol.  It is not meant to be used to write data or modify the file.  From you r description I can't tell the difference between the code that is working and not working.  Can you explain better?

Comment: @jdweng the code that give's the error is this client.WriteAllText("C:/Users/Public/Documents/Test.json", "jeff"); it's the last line of  the code. in the function that I gave.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that any of the methods such as ChangeDirectory and UploadFile expect a path relative to the WorkingDirectory property. As a result, I fixed my issue by changing it to

```
client.ChangeDirectory(@"/other_directory");
```

Hope that helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, the folder delimiter is a backslash `"\"` not a slash `"/"`

Rather use

```
client.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\Documents\Test.json", "jeff");
//                  ^---------------------- Notice the @ that will automatically escape the \
```

Comment: oke this doe get  rid of the error, but now it doesn't do anthing.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is being thrown due to incorrect path to the sftp.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this message you can get the sftp working directory first and then use it to build your destination path.

```
string destPath=Path.Combine(sftp.WorkingDirectory,"whatever_your_directory",Path.GetFileName(sourcefile));   

client.UploadFile(fs, destPath);
```